# Azure Data Factory not able to parameterize Key Vault secretName inside Blob Storage linked service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create some kind of `AzureBlobStorage` linked service which will retrieve it's `accountKey` from Key Vault by dynamically provided `secretName`. I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#account-key-authentication).
So for this I've prepared this json:

```
{
    "name": "AzureBlobStorageLinkedServiceWithDynamicStorageAccountKeysFromKeyVault",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=@{linkedService().storageAccountName}",
            "accountKey": {
              "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
              "store": {
                  "referenceName": "AzureKeyVaultWithStorageAccountsSecrets",
                  "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
              },
              "secretName": {
                "type": "Expression",
                "value": "@{linkedService().storageAccountName}"
              }
            }
          
        },
        "parameters": {
            "storageAccountName": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "fixmeaccountname"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to test this I'm getting error

```
Invalid storage connection string provided to 'UnknownLocation'. Check the storage connection string in configuration. Duplicate setting 'AccountName' found.
```

If I remove `AccountName=@{linkedService().storageAccountName}` from `connectionString` then I have this error

```
Invalid storage connection string provided to 'UnknownLocation'. Check the storage connection string in configuration. Duplicate setting 'AccountKey' found.
```

Is it possible to have such linked service with parameterized key vault?

Answer (score 0):

The secret on the KV is it connectionstring or just the key ? I think you are storing the connectionstring  as a secret , please try out with just the key and it should work .